# Trouble in xamarin publishing in app store and in TestFlight

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, testflight, xamarin-studio

'm new to Xamarin. i am having trouble in publishing the ipa file. I have taken the archives using xamarin studio. i trying to load the ipa file through application loader. it load the ipa file to the app store. i can see the ipa file in the store and in TestFlight .when i try to give the file to test it says a warning like..

"Some builds are missing the beta entitlement, or were uploaded with a beta version of Xcode, and cannot be tested."

My Xcode is updated. do i need to download the latest version of the OS too ? or any other thing that i am missing .

Can any one help me in this.

Comment: This would likely be a good candidate for help from Xamarin.iOS support team.

Comment: hank you for the suggestion. In my case the problem was with mt iOs SDK path. It was pointing to the beta version of Xcode. so i changed the path and it worked....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have selected the `AppStore` build configuration and to iOS device when you build a test version.

[image: Build configuration]

Another 'trick' is to use the 'Archive for publishing' menu option when you right-click the project.

[image: Archive for publishing option]

This will give you relevant feedback about how you should build a package that can be distributed.

Is you do not have the distribution profile the build will fail and you have to get into the [Apple Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/) and create one for your app.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. In my case the problem was with mt iOs SDK path. It was pointing to the beta version of Xcode. so i changed the path and it worked....

Comment: Ah didn't hear that one before. Glad you got it working!